# is there real 64bit version of PHP 5.6 for windows?

Tags: php, 64-bit, php-5.6

On 32bit php, the PHP_INT_MAX (max integer value) is much lower, and causes problems.
When looking online to get local laragon test server up, found old versions for windows archived here: https://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/archives/

Problem is, even those links ending x64, for example **php-5.6.29-Win32-VC11-x64.zip** is really not 64bit version, i tried running it, and if i echo the PHP_INT_MAX value, i can clearly see it is 32bit mode, bc PHP_INT_SIZE is only 2147483647

Is there an actual real 64bit php 5.6 for windows?
I know there is a linux version because i have one running on one linux server, but need to have one up on local windows pc. I know there is a way to use wsl or virtual ubuntu etc, but really woul dlove to work right from windows..

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: There were third-party AMD64 builds, but they were nothing but the same source code compiled for that platform. We didn't have proper 64-bit support until PHP/7. Sorry, that's the way it is.

Comment: _"PHP_INT_MAX  is much lower, and causes problems"_ - may I ask _exactly_ what problkems you're having? Because it sounds like a problem with your application's design rather than with PHP itself.

Comment: @Dai well, specifically im running some really hungry queries on table w 11M records... and try to measure the memory_get_usage() where real usage shown on 64 bit machines is about 6GB for the query...- and simply said that INT limit in bytes is enough to show about 2GB (2 147 483 647 bytes), not more

Comment: @PM_KLS What do you mean by "real usage" (in `memory_get_usage`)? If your PHP process is 32-bit then it is _impossible_ for PHP to consume more than 2GB (or 3-4GB, depending on your setup). And if your PHP script is consuming 2GB+ of RAM then your PHP script is _doing something wrong_. PHP is not an appropriate tool/language for OLAP, which is what it sounds like you're doing...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following statement misses from the [current PHP documentation page about integers](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php) but it was present back in the days when PHP 5 was the most recent version:

> 64-bit platforms usually have a maximum value of about 9E18, except on Windows prior to PHP 7, where it was always 32 bit.

I could find it in the [documentation of PHP 5](https://php-legacy-docs.zend.com/manual/php5/en/language.types.integers). There are links to the documentation of previous versions of PHP on the bottom of  [the documentation start page](https://www.php.net/docs.php).

I would say that the only solution to your problem is to upgrade PHP to version 7 or, even better, to the most recent version ([8.2](https://www.php.net/releases/8.2/en.php)). Or use Linux for development (it is much better than Windows for web development). Or both.

Comment: thanks @axiac for explanation, so it really generally sucks there and its not me, thank you for nice explanation with details